# "full" transition behavior on Chrome when using rotate3d

Tags: css, google-chrome

```css
.item {
    transition: transform 1s linear;
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
}
.item:hover {
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 450deg);
}
```

In the above example Chrome rotates `.item` a full 450 degrees. While Firefox, Edge, and Safari rotate between the beginning and end states resulting in a smaller 90 degree rotation.

This only seems to occur with `rotate3d`. Using `rotateZ` makes all browsers rotate the full 450.

Guessing this is a bug within Chrome? Does anyone know the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#funcdef-rotate3d) well enough to confirm?

Demo on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/kellengreen/pen/zELPpm).

Comment: This sounds more like a bug in the **other browsers** not Chrome

Comment: Seems to be an issue with 3d..since `rotate(450deg)` seems to work fine

Comment: Yes, I'm not convinced Chrome is at fault here either. It just looked suspicious standing all by itself.